# How to fix the amount of comments displayed for each post?

Tags: mysql, comments

I've received an old wordpress 2.8 and successfully upgraded to WP3.2.1.
I've just discovered that the amount of comments displayed in the WP Admin 's list of posts is wrong.

Would you know how i could fix that by, perhaps, running a clever SQL update query in the database, that would fetch the real number of comments associated to a post and update the post row accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nailed it:

```
UPDATE wp_posts as p SET comment_count =(SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_post_ID`=p.ID);
```